# Did the Mad Clown that resulted in teeth marks in Batman's leather thong come again?

Tags: dc, batman, character-identification

In [When did Batman’s leather thong get teeth marks in it?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152055/when-did-batman-s-leather-thong-get-teeth-marks-in-it), I learned that the thong gained its teeth marks from Batman doing an [Iron Jaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_jaw_(circus)) trick, descending a wire to attack the "Mad Clown".

[image: Mad Clown image]

Is this character exclusive to the flashback or was there some other issue where they appeared? My attempts to search were thwarted by Joker having a nickname of "Mad Clown", which means most results related to him. I tried excluding "Joker", but got nothing, possibly because the writer said something along the lines of "That's when we saw the Mad Clown (not the Joker) take over the circus".

So, was this the only appearance of the "Mad Clown"?

Comment: This is terrible news! I thought the Mad Clown had bitten Batman's leather thong, but it turns out Batman bit his own leather thong when he saw the Mad Clown!

Comment: Yes, I too should like to learn as the the frequency of the mad clown's coming while Batman had his teeth deeply sunken into his leather thong. For research purposes.